# ShareStatusTask identificar meu app no Facebook?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Estou usando o código

```
Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.ShareStatusTask status = new Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.ShareStatusTask();
status.Status = "Eu, " + sNome + ", sou doador de órgãos, baixe o app e seja um também: http://www.windowsphone.com/pt-br/store/app/sou-doador/82cbd25a-923d-4336-ab98-6b93d71ae929  ou faça o cadastro online aqui: http://www.adote.org.br/cadastre.htm - Não pense na doação de órgãos como 'oferecer uma parte de você para que um estranho possa viver'. Na realidade é 'um estranho que oferece o corpo para que uma parte de você possa continuar vivendo'.";
status.Show();
```

Para criar uma string na qual será compartilhada por diversos apps (dependendo dos que o usuário tenha instalado), quero saber se há como eu definir para o Facebook, a origem da postagem, exemplo de post:

```
XXXXXX - via Nome do App
```

Onde o texto depois do traço (-) é adicionado automaticamente pelo Facebook, também contendo um link para o app e seu ícone. Há como eu fazer o Facebook identificar meu app?